# Is it possible to make JSON_MERGE_PATCH function in mysql case insensitive (i.e. Ignore Case)

Tags: mysql, json, collation

By default the comparison of JSON values in MySQL is case-sensitive, so JSON_MERGE_PATCH is case sensitive.

This implies that a JSON_MERGE_PATCH on following row in a MySQL table results in adding rather than replacing the JSON value.

**Value before JSON_MERGE_PATCH**

[image]

**Value after JSON_MERGE_PATCH**

[image]

Is there any possibility to make JSON_MERGE_PATCH case insensitive, so that it results in **{"A":"B"}** only by replacing the lower case value **{"a":"b"}**

Comment: `JSON_MERGE_PATCH(LOWER(json_column), LOWER(@json_literal))`

Comment: Using LOWER results in storing data in a different case than the one provided in user input

Comment: *Using LOWER results in storing data in a different case than the one provided in user input* Please decide - do you want to store case sensitivity or not... In any case you may create your own custom function which performs needed action using common string and JSON functions.